# Graph input (networkx) for Dataloader in Pytorch

Tags: graph, pytorch, networkx

I am newbie in Graph using Deep learning. 
I'm trying to create `DataLoader` for Pytorch to training.

I using `networkx` to save my graph, then get `dataset` from util of  torch_geometric to have dataset for `DataLoader`. But I can not train my model. My code:

```py
#import...
G = nx.karate_club_graph()
dataset = torch_geometric.utils.from_networkx(G)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

for data in dataloader:
   print(data) # Error here: TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string
```

So how do I put Graph Input for Pytorch to train?

Comment: Have run into the same problem today. Did you manage to find the issue?

Comment: Not yet. I have to rewrite dataloader for Python using adjacency matrix of graph.
It's quiet slow for pre-training.

Comment: For the record, I have a custom dataset. It has edge_attr, edge_index, x, y. If I do 

train_dataset, test_dataset = dataset[:5000], dataset[5000:]

I then get: 

TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string